# How can i change my my URL with .htaccess on Symfony 2

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, url, router

I would like to change my url using only .htaccess, how can i change my url from this : `http://s1rd-ubuntu-01/vpscraplist/web/app_dev.php/myproject/`  to this `http://vpscraplist/platform/` or this `http://vpscraplist/`

i have also more pages on my project as `http://s1rd-ubuntu-01/vpscraplist/web/app_dev.php/myproject/add` and `http://s1rd-ubuntu-01/vpscraplist/web/app_dev.php/myproject/edit`  ...

I've already used thoses scripte but not work for me :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Change below before deploying to production
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

or this one :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^/web/app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^/web/app.php - [L]

# Fix the bundles folder
RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Change below before deploying to production
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

Thank you and sorry about my english  !

Comment: do you have access/rights to change apache configuration?

Comment: yes i have acces/right, but never done before, can you tell how and where can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best approach is to keep the default htaccess of symfony, and to configure your apache vhost as explained there:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

(don't forget to enable the apache rewrite if it is not dude: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` )

create the vhost file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite.conf
```

with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.net
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myprojectSymfony/web
    <Directory /var/www/myprojectSymfony/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you have have created your virtual file, you must enable them

```
sudo a2ensite yoursite.conf
```

When you are finished, you need to restart Apache to make these changes take effect:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ive done this like this: 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myproject.vpccpp.fr
        ServerAlias www.myproject.vpccpp.fr
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/web
        <Directory //var/www/html/myproject/web>
                   AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        </Directory>`
...

but nothing change, do i have to do some command line before or after to get work?

Comment: Doesn't workn ive done all the steps, but doesnt work with any of those urls : `platform/`   or `http://vpscraplist.vpccpp.fr/platform/`